# nuSOAP: error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: php, soap

I'm getting an error while creating a nuSOAP server with PHP:

> error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
>
> Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

My code:

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';
require 'lib/nusoap.php';
//Select data from database
function fetchDataEmp($id){
global $conn;
$getData = "select * from user where id= :id";
$stmt=$conn->prepare($getData);
$stmt->bindParam(':id',$id);
$stmt->execute();
$data=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return json_encode($data);
$conn = null;}
$server=new nusoap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("demo"."urn:demo");
$server->register('fetchDataEmp',
      array('id' => 'xsd:int'),  //parameter
      array('data' => 'xsd:string')  //output
      );  

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);  

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using PHP 7 try file_get_contents instead this should resolve your issue.

Replace

```
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

With

```
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```